# Read DHCP options with Scapy

Tags: scapy, dhcp

Using Scapy I am able to send a DHCP Discover and receive a DHCP Offer:

```
dhcp_discover = Ether(...) / IP(...) / UDP(...) / BOOTP(...) / DHCP(...)
dhcp_offer = srp1(dhcp_discover, iface="eno1", timeout=1)
```

For the moment, I read options values like so:

```
dhcp_offer.getLayer(DHCP).fields["options"]
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
[('message-type', 2), ('server_id', '192.168.0.1'), ('lease_time', '600), ...]
```

It works but it is not very handy!

I am sure there is a better solution to just read the value of the option `'server_id'` for example and avoid having to parse the list of tuples. The documentation is not very helpful on this case.

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure scapy provides a more "handy" way to access the options but you can construct a dictionary from this tuple list and then easily access option values by providing option names as keys:

```py
opts = [('message-type', 2), ('server_id', '192.168.0.1'), ('lease_time', 600)]
opts_as_dict = dict(opts)
print(opts_as_dict['lease_time'])
```